# How to save created excel file to local server in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have a codes in my controller that let me creates an excel file.  Now what I want is to save the excel file in my local server or server.  How to do that?

I want the excel file saved in this location: http://localhost/reportrepository/filename.xlsx

Here are my codes algo:

```
try
{
    var workbook = new Workbook();
    // some other codes that creates the workbook....

    // save workbook here to local server....

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can access the server's file system normally.  The tricky part is to figure out how to access your web application's directory structure.  Try something like this:

```
string workingDirectory = Request.Params["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"];
string workbookPath = workingDirectory + @"\ReportRepository\filename.xls";
workbook.SaveAs(workbookPath, ...);
```

Comment: workbook.SaveAs().. NO available .SaveAs method for Workbook.

Comment: [Documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx)